# Javascript OOP use function inside object

Tags: javascript, oop

I have JS object

```
var widget = {
    check_balance: function(){...},
    function_called_in_init: function(){
         .....
         this.check_balance();
    };
};
```

this is code screenshot for better understanding.. [image: pic]

and when it try to call `this.check_balance();` it returns me error `TypeError: this.check_balanceis not a function`

the question would be - how to call function inside object which was also created inside object?

Also I can't init this function at the moment when all object is inited, becouse this is a recursion with ajax callback.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your snippet. Did you mean those first two `;` to be `,`?

Comment: it was only snippet bug, the code looks different

Comment: Provided ; changed to , and you call widget.function_called_in_init(). It should work.

Comment: You dont need the `this` calling it directly will work as intended.

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan it will not work becouse this is inside object.

Comment: Working for me https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=u5FcjI26Do

Comment: Oh my bad it works with this for me no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little tricky to see what you are asking but the gist of it is you are looking to have the correct context. The tool for that is the `whatever.bind(theContext)` function. You pass in `theContext` to the object and that makes `theContext` object the context of `whatever`.

```
var parent = {
    foo: function () {
        var widget = {
            check_balance: function(){ console.log('checking'); },
            function_called_in_init: function(){
                 this.bar();
            }.bind(this),
        };
        widget.function_called_in_init();
    },
    bar: function () {
        console.log('bar');
    },
};

parent.foo();
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1ewtp7y/1/)

[bind documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

Use private function and closure

```
var widget = (function() {
    var check_balance = function() {
        //do what your check_balance has to do
    }
    return {
        check_balance: check_balance,
        function_called_in_init: function(){
            .....
            check_balance();
        };
    };
})();
```